# VBA Selenium with Chrome - Want to add Error Handler in VBA only

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

1. Want to add Two Things in Error Handler, If script get `stuck` in any line, like if Webpage does not meet its requirement, it shows the `Alert pop`
2. for this WebPage Requirements is like, Name character length must be >3 or Mobile number digits must be = 10
3. Then I want to refresh `‪bot.Refresh` the page then want to - Click OK (or Accept) in the Alert Popup `bot.SwitchToAlert.Accept` then `Sub End` - all this stuff in an Error Handling.‬
4. After a successful run of Error Handling, the script has to run from the beginning (from #Patient Name)
5. I want to add a Column in Excel where which line got an error, gave me **Not Done** and which got no error gave me **Done**

```
Sub Automate()
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "/"
    
'#Patient Name
    bot.FindElementByName("patient_name").SendKeys "Value"

'#Age-in
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 4) = "Years" Then
        bot.FindElementById("age_year").Click
        bot.FindElementByName("age").SendKeys "Value"
    Else
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 4) = "Months" Then
        bot.FindElementById("age_month").Click
        bot.FindElementByName("age").SendKeys "Value"
    Else
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 4) = "Days" Then
        bot.FindElementById("age_day").Click
        bot.FindElementByName("age").SendKeys "Value"
    End If
    End If
    End If

'#Mobile Number
    bot.FindElementById("contact_number").SendKeys "Value"

'#Gender
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 6) = "Male" Then
        Set ListDD = bot.FindElementById("gender")
        ListDD.AsSelect.SelectByText "Value"
    Else
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 6) = "Female" Then
        Set ListDD = bot.FindElementById("gender")
        ListDD.AsSelect.SelectByText "Value"
    Else
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 6) = "Transgender" Then
        Set ListDD = bot.FindElementById("gender")
        ListDD.AsSelect.SelectByText "Value"
    End If
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle errors in VBA you can use `On Error Goto <Label>` or `On Error Resume Next`

For `On Error GoTo <Label>` in case runtime exceptions is occurred execution control goes to the `<Label>` block and start execution from there.

For `On Error Resume Next` it simply ignores the exception and starts execution from the next line. At first glance it might seem stupid as it might lead to a spiral of errors and result in unpredicted behaviour. However with careful development it does have it's own fare share of usage.

In this particular case `On Error Goto <Label>` would be more suitable and it will look something like this.

```
Sub Automate()
START: 'Labled code block indicating start of our execution
    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLE:
    'Your code
    
    
    
    Sheet1.Cells(Row, 10).Value = "DONE"            'Change the column index according to your column of choice
    Exit Sub    'Or Exit Function if it is inside a function
ERROR_HANDLE: 'Labled code block defining error handling behavior
    bot.Refresh
    bot.SwitchToAlert.Accept
    Sheet1.Cells(Row, 10).Value = "NOT DONE"        'Change the column index according to your column of choice
    'If you want to start again from start immediately from here uncomment next line. However this can potentially become an infinite loop.
    'GoTo START
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks it solves my half problem in script, the other half is .. I want to add a Column in Excel where which line got an error, gave me **Not Done** and which got no error gave me **Done**

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last point earlier. I have updated my answer. If that solves your query please upvote and and mark it as answer to close the thread.

Comment: Yes, brother i want to close this, can you please have a look on this .. it's perfectly working on Not Done Statement, but on **Done** part, it is also going to `ERROR_HANLDLE`, .. Why is this happening? its not supposed to go in `ERROR_HANDLE` .. and i also added the error's pic, where you can know that, VBA printed DONE, n its still going to Error_Handler

Comment: You can add one `Exit Function` or `Exit Sub` statement(depending on the code block being `function` or `sub`) just after the `DONE` part and before `ERROR_HANLDLE` . It should get out of the `function` or `sub` from there upon successful execution. From the snip it seems to be inside a `Function`. So you should use `Exit Function` just after the highlighted line.

Comment: In case you are returning something from the function you need to set the return value before `Exit` statement properly.